# Using Selenium to find an image with a given src link and click

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

This is the html code of a website I want to scrape

```html
<div>
  <div class="activityinstance">
    <a class="" onclick="" href="https://www.blablabla.com">
      <img src="http://www.blablabla.com/justapicture.jpg"  class="iconlarge activityicon" alt="" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true">
      <span class="instancename">title<span class="accesshide "> text
      </span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

IMAGELINK = "http://www.blablabla.com/justapicture.jpg"

My aim is to find in particular page all of the hrefs that are associated with IMAGELINK using python.
the picture from this url tend to be shown multiple times and I want to recieve all the links so I could click on them.

I tried to find elements by class name "a" to extract all of the links in the page, and that way if I could find their xPath I could just format "/img" and get attribute "src" from that element.
But the problem is I haven't found a way to extract the xPath with given webdriver element.

NOTE: I don't have access to the Xpath of the element unless I write some function to generate it

Comment: what have you tried? Show the code.

Answer (score 2):

Find all elements with tag `img` and print the `src` attribute:

```
imgs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img")
for img in imgs:
    print(img.get_attribute("src"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he wanted the parent href with the img src which equals

```
imgs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[src='http://www.blablabla.com/justapicture.jpg']/parent::a")
for img in imgs:
    print(img.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: You are right, this is what I wanted. but it doesn't work the way you suggest. it returns  Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[src="https://moodle.technion.ac.il/theme/image.php/fordson/assign/1603222249/icon"]/parent::a"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)

Comment: I guess this is because the image is deeper in the tree than just //img[src=....]

Comment: Use @src instead of src